# Get index array of value changes or first distinct values from array of Objects

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

I have a sorted array of objects that contains 3 doubles, lets call them x, y and z.  I need to create an array of indexes for each transition point, example:

```
index   x   y   z
------------------
  0  |  3 | 2 | 1
  1  |  4 | 3 | 1
  2  |  3 | 1 | 1
  3  |  1 | 3 | 2
  4  |  3 | 1 | 2
  5  |  1 | 3 | 3
  6  |  1 | 3 | 3
```

Should give me the array {3,5}  as that is the point where z changes, I have tried
`var ans = myObjectArr.Select(a => a.z).Distinct().ToList();`but that simply gives me a list of the values themselves and not the index they are in the object array.  The array is very large and i would like to avoid iterating my way through it discreetly.  I feel like i'm just missing something silly and any help would be appreciated. Generating a list or an array would both be acceptable.

EDIT: I was under the impression that using Linq was faster than doing it iteratively, after reading comments i find this not to be the case and because of this Charlieface's answer is the best one for my problem.

Comment: "*avoid iterating my way through it discreetly*" - Yeah so, any solution you use will need to do this anyway. Just use a for loop, and ponder about how many printable characters you can reduce or whether you can get it on one line later

Comment: Lots of possible approaches. See duplicate for example. If after doing some actual research, reviewing the information available to you, and making a genuine attempt to implement a solution, you run into some _specific_ issue you're unable to solve, please feel free to post another question. If you do, make sure you include in that one a proper [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what the code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: `var ans = myObjectArr.Select((a, index) => new {z = a.z, index = index}).DistinctBy(z => z.z).ToList();` likely works if you use MoreLinq as well.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I don't know how they're going to avoid O(N), at least in the worst case. They didn't say anything in the post about an interview; just that they _"would like to avoid iterating"_. I'd like all my code to be written for me by the computer, without any effort on my own. That someone _"would like"_ something doesn't mean it's possible, nor that answers that don't comply with that aren't answers to their question.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I was under the impression that Linq was faster than doing it iteratively with a for loop based on things i have read. I stated i wanted to avoid it not that i refused to do it.  I should also add that this is not an interview question, I am a firmware engineer and i find claiming this is an interview question to be unhelpful.

Comment: @user3599976 The way I read the question it looked like interview one, sorry about that. LINQ solution indeed can be faster than wrong solution for a given problem (like O(n^2) intersection of sets) but never faster than optimally coded one (as LINQ is just code, just a bit more generalized and thus slower, plus it can't handle cases where information is not directly available - i.e. there are no optimizations for sorted sequences). In your case since it is impossible to sort 2d/3d values you have sorting does not help at all - so linear search is fine...

Comment: ...  if you would only need to get indexes where values change from array of single comparable values (not really case for double either) and number of distinct elements is much smaller than total number of items (like 1...1, 5....5, 7...7 each of integer repeated 100+ times) than binary search could speed code up. But again it does not look you can sort the array (despite the question claiming it is "sorted") nor can really compare items (as doubles are not very suitable for exact comparison anyway, also maybe you have fixed set of possible values - than you can compare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var lastZ = myObjectArr[0].z;
var zIndexes = new List<int>();
for(var i = 1; i < myObjectArr.Length; i++)
{
    if(myObjectArr[i] != lastZ)
    {
        lastZ = myObjectArr[i];
        zIndexes.Add(i);
    }
}
// or you can use obscure Linq code if it makes you feel better
var zIndexes = myObjectArr
    .Select((o, i) => (o, i))
    .Skip(1)
    .Aggregate(
        new List<int>(),
        (list, tuple) => {
            if(tuple.o.z != lastZ)
            {
                lastZ = tuple.o.z;
                list.Add(tuple.i);
            }
            return list;
        } );
```

Comment: How this " to avoid iterating my way through it"?

Comment: You have to iterate somehow. Even Linq iterates

Comment: OPs (probably interview) question states that array is sorted (probably by the Z column). So you need to either show the way of finding boundaries  in sorted array  
 or explain that it does not really matter (both fine answers, one likely would need to explain why it does not really matter anyway so)

Comment: I will probably use this, i have found that Linq solutions typically take less time than iterating it with for loops but by reading other answers there does not seem to be a simple solution.  
A comment to Alexi, it's not an interview question its a real world problem im having.

Comment: @user3599976 I totally misread your question - I assume that you have 3 numbers sorted in an array... But after re-reading you have just list of triples of arbitrary values. I have no idea how you sorting them but all 3 can't be really sequential... so linear iteration and with comparing to the previous one is the best you can get (indeed it is exactly what you said you already have in the question... so very confusing how this one is different... ohhh well)

Comment: @user3599976 You may find MoreLinq useful for these kinds of issues.

Comment: @user3599976 Linq usually takes **longer** due to extra instantiation and indirection. `for` loops over arrays will nearly always be faster